# How does the google batch API respond when user beyond his API quota (google developer batch/admin-sdk/directory/v1/)

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am using Google admin-sdk batch API for most of my use cases. I wonder how does google respond when the user hits rateLimit (API Quota). Does it set the outer response as 403 or individual response with 403 response code?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits), the API will return a JSON code with three different Reasons, depending of the issue causing the exception:

[image]

For example:

```
{
   "error":{
      "errors":[
         {
            "domain":"usageLimits",
            "reason":"dailyLimitExceeded",
            "message":"Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up",
            "extendedHelp":"https://code.google.com/apis/console"
         }
      ],
      "code":403,
      "message":"Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"
   }
}
```